# How to make a multi-argument Pipe in Angular 2.0.0

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm trying to implement a Truncate pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({ name: 'truncate' })
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, amount: number, truncateChar: string) : string {
        console.log("amount", amount);
        console.log("truncateChar", truncateChar);
        let limit = amount ? amount : 10;
        let trail = truncateChar ? truncateChar : '...';
        return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
    }
}
```

Somehow in my template it always prints `undefined` for `truncateChar`, though it does pick up the `amount`.

In my template I tried the following syntaxes (on their own turn):

```
{{ item.name | truncate: 20 : "a" }}
{{ item.name | truncate: 20 : 'a' }}
{{ item.name | truncate: 20 : a }}
```

How could I implement this using multiple arguments (max characters and optional trailing character)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your `pipe`, this works perfectly for me:

```
{{ name | truncate: 20 : 'c' }}
```

In console I get:

> amount 20
>
> truncateChar c

Your problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Yea, no idea what was going on. Ah... since it is in another folder (shared now), I guess the build didn't pick up the change. Though wait, I was still seeing the "console.log".... very strange. But indeed, now it does work.